# XSLT 1.0 - How to compare two node-set values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, node-set

**Compare two node-sets and get a new one with unique values only 
        result**

To be specific create nodeset3 where value is in nodeset1 but not in nodeset2
(so basically  nodeset3=nodeset1-nodeset2 in set theory).

This is node set 1 with some values

```
<xsl:variable name="node1">
  <footnotes>
    <fn>a</fn>
    <fn>b</fn>
    <fn>c</fn>
    <fn>d</fn>
  </footnotes>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="nodeset1" select="msxml:node-set($node1)" />
```

here is nodeset2

a
       b

result should be

```
 nodeset3
<footnotes>
  <fn>c</fn>
  <fn>d</fn>
</footnotes>
```

I have tried this without success

```
<xsl:variable name="node3">
  <xsl:for-each select="$nodeset1/fn">
    <xsl:if test="$nodeset2 != ./text()">
      <fn2>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </fn2>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="nodeset3" select="msxml:node-set($node3)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <xsl:variable name="node3">  
<xsl:for-each select="$nodeset1/fn">
<xsl:if test="not($nodeset2/element =current()/text())">
<fn><xsl:value-of select="."/></fn>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:valieable>
```

sorry took some time but got it

Comment: You can move the filter from `xsl:if` into `xsl:for-each` and get rid of the `xsl:if`. 
`<xsl:for-each select="$nodeset1/fn[not(. =  $nodeset2/element)]">`